# Posting Panels Twice (Understanding pre-init)

Tags: vb.net, webforms

I have a page that dynamically builds a group of Panels based on a SQL call.

**Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish.**

When the page is first loaded several `Panels` are dynamically built. Lets say there is one panel for each State: CA, NJ, FL, etc.

If a user clicks on one of the panels (ie. one of the states) a SQL call is made and brings back a list of cities within that state. The page then dynamically builds the panels only this time listing the cities within the state clicked. When the user clicks on of the cities it calls SQL and find all of the schools listed in that city and displays them in panels (again one school per panel).

**What's Happening**

When the states are loaded they display fine. Though when the user clicks a particular state the page reloads and then displays all of states and all of the cities after listing all of the states instead of just listing the cities.

The proper cities are being listed so the SQL call is working.

**Solution**

I know several things.

1. ViewState is remembering the panels previously created and loading them
   *or*
2. When I step through the code it's loading both the states and then the cities.
3. Dynamic controls are handed during the pre-init stage of the life-cycle.

**Question**

How can I solve this problem? I didn't post any relevant code because there is a decent amount of it to sift though. If parts of it are needed / wanted ask and I can edit this post.

I have already searched though Microsoft's documentation and the like so please don't post links to those unless you are fairly certain they will help with the issue.

Comment: In your situation, I would probably throw it out and use AJAX. Or possibly render everything and then display it using Javascript. If you really don't want javascript option personally, I find creating controls in the code behind generally undesirable. I'd use repeaters to create whatever it is you need. As to the problem you've mentioned, it sounds like you're adding the cities in the wrong place. They need to be child controls to the states.